# How do I use hot-module-reload in projects generated by aurelia-cli?

Tags: aurelia

I have a project generated with aurelia-cli with default options. It's built with `au build`, run with `au run --env dev --watch` and uses requirejs behind the scene. How do I add hot-module-reload into the mix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no hot module reload support for Aurelia CLI at the moment. The team is working on a Webpack-based support, which should land soon, as stated in [their latest update](http://blog.aurelia.io/2016/12/08/big-aurelia-release-update/):

> That's what our new hot module reload enables. We've got a preliminary version of this up and running and integrated into our forthcoming Webpack update. It enables editing Views, ViewModels, related components (such as ValueConverters and BindingBehaviors) and CSS without reloading the full website.

As you said, Aurelia CLI is currently using RequireJS for module loading. A support for Webpack is coming to Aurelia CLI sometime in future. When that happens, we should also get hot module reload support.

If you cannot wait, your options are to either switch to Webpack based solution or build your own support for it, which could be pretty hard to do.

Comment: Hi Miroslav. Is there an update on when Webpack support will be added to Aurelia CLI?

Comment: Last official mention of Webpack was a month ago in [this post](http://blog.aurelia.io/2017/01/02/aurelia-2017-resolutions/). You could ask on Aurelia's Gitter channel: https://gitter.im/aurelia/Discuss

Comment: Thank you Miroslav!

Comment: webpack is [officially](http://blog.aurelia.io/2017/08/18/aurelia-cli-webpack-update/) out.